# Google Earth Engine Filter seasons independent from year

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter

Is something like this possible? and how ?

```
Image.Collection.filterDate('20xx-04-01','20xx-09-31')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. you can filter so that collections only contain images that are within a range of the day of the year.

```
// only include images that are between day 60 and day 90
var marchImages = ImageCollection.filter(ee.Filter.dayOfYear(60,90))
```